# How can I send a Success Message with compact in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to send a success message with a compact but it didn't work for me a message does not appear?

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $brand=$request->get('searchbrand');
    $model=$request->get('searchmodel');
    $cars=car::where('brand','like','%'.$brand.'%')
    ->where(function ($query)use($model) {
        $query->where('model','like','%'.$model.'%');
    })->get();
    return view('cars.index',compact('cars'))
    ->with('success','Results Car');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `compact()` or `with()`, but generally not both.

Here's some options:

1. Use `->with()` with a single `array`:

```
return view('cars.index')->with(['cars' => $cars, 'success' => 'Results Car']);
```

2. Chain `->with()` calls:

```
return view('cars.index')->with('cars', $cars)->with('success', 'Results Car');
```

3. Pass an `array` instead of `with()` or `compact()`:

```
return view('cars.index', ['cars' => $cars, 'success' => 'Results Car']);
```

4. Use `compact()` with a `$success` variable:

```
$success = 'Results Car';
return view('cars.index', compact('cars', 'success'));
```

Comment: in those cases it wont appears in blade file with Session::get('success') right 
how may i make it appears ?

Comment: by foreach maybe ?

Comment: in `cars/index.blade.php`, it would be available as `$success`, not `session()->get('success')`.

Comment: No problem :) Sidenote, if you do `return redirect(...)->with('success', 'Message')`, then you have to access via `session()->get('success')`, but `return view(...)->with('success', 'Message')` converts it to a variable `$success`